# What happens if a vocation wears equipment for another vocation? 

Tags: tibia

Let's see if there are any other Tibia players on Gaming SE!

A few updates ago equipment went from being universal to being vocation-specific.  For example, [Knight Legs](http://tibia.wikia.com/wiki/Knight_Legs) can now only be used by knights and paladins.  What happens if a sorcerer or druid wears them?  Do they have absolutely no effect or do they have a reduced effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spellcasters can't even put them on, but if it's still there (put there before the update) it has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Oh gosh!  I'd better not take my legs off, then... not that it will make any difference :/